# How to run a windows cmd automatically in php

Tags: php, windows, cmd

I have prepared this php webservice

```
<?php
$user_name = "root";
$user_pass = "";
$host_name = "localhost";
$db_name = "dbupload";

$con = mysqli_connect($host_name,$user_name,$user_pass,$db_name);

if ($con) {
  $image = $_POST["image"];
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $sql = "insert into imageinfo(name) values ('$name')";
  $upload_path = "B:/Smart_Music/Emotion_Model/images/$name.jpg";

  if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    file_put_contents($upload_path,base64_decode($image));
    $reponse=array();
        $reponse["response"]="Image Uploaded Successfully";
        echo json_encode($reponse);
  }  
  else {
    $reponse=array();
   $reponse["response"]="Failure";
   echo json_encode($reponse);
  }
}
else {
  $reponse=array();
 $reponse["response"]="Failure";
 echo json_encode($reponse);
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

What I want to achieve is to execute automaticlly some windows commands after sending the response.

this is the commands :

```
cd /d B:\Smart_Music\Emotion_Model\src
activate Emotion
python image_emotion_demo.py ../images/Selected_Photo.jpg
```

Comment: Have you looked at the php exec(), passthru() and system() functions? It sounds like what you are looking for. A word of caution - sending user input to these commands can be very dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec or shell_exec`

```
<?php 

// Use ls command to shell_exec 
// function 
$output = shell_exec('ls'); 

// Display the list of all file 
// and directory 
echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; 
?>
```

Output will be **for me**

```
gfg.php
index.html
geeks.php
```

**Be sure if its not a local machine this functions is not disabled for security reasons**

Comment: I want to use that in my local machine

Comment: okey its not problem now you can just use the shell_exec and you will be good